# Orbiting objects with equal spacing AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a monster that produces crystals. I want each crystal to orbit the monster, but when there is more than one crystal, I want them to orbit at an equal distance from each other. I've been trying to get this to work using two blocks of code I already have, but each one does something different and i need one block of code that does it all.

This block simply allows an object to orbit another:

```
orbitRadius = 110;
angle += orbitSpeed;
rad = (angle * (Math.PI / 180));
orbitX = monster.x + orbitRadius * Math.cos(rad);
orbitY = monster.y + orbitRadius * Math.sin(rad);
```

Here's a video of what it looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACclpQBsjPo

This block of code arranges crystals around the monster based on the amount of crystals there are:

```
radius = 110;
angle = ((Math.PI * 2) / targetArray.length) * targetArray.indexOf(this);
orbitX = monster.x - (radius * Math.cos(angle));
orbitY = monster.y - (radius * Math.sin(angle));
```

And here's this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY0mBHc2A8U

I do not know how to both space the crystals equally **and** make them circle around the monster at the same time. What needs to be done in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Hierarchical way: put crystals into the same container so they spread equally (like you are doing on the second video) then rotate the container.

2) Math way.

Implementation:

```
public class Orbiter extends Sprite
{
    // Pixels.
    public var radius:Number = 100;

    // Degrees per second.
    public var speed:Number = 360;

    public var items:Array;
    public var lastTime:int;

    public function start()
    {
        stop();

        rotation = 0;
        items = new Array;
        lastTime = getTimer();

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
    }

    public function stop():void
    {
        items = null;

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
    }

    public function onFrame(e:Event = null):void
    {
        var aTime:int = getTimer();

        rotation += speed * (aTime - lastTime) / 1000;
        lastTime = aTime;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            // Get the object.
            var anItem:DisplayObject = items[i];

            // Get the object's designated position.
            var aPos:Point = getPosition(i);

            // Follow the position smoothly.
            anItem.x += (aPos.x - anItem.x) / 10;
            anItem.y += (aPos.y - anItem.y) / 10;
        }
    }

    private function getPosition(index:int):Point
    {
        // Calculate the angle with regard to the present items amount.
        var anAngle:Number = (rotation - 360 / items.length) * Math.PI / 180;
        var result:Point = new Point;

        // Figure the position with regard to (x,y) offset.
        result.x = x + radius * Math.cos(anAngle);
        result.y = y + radius * Math.sin(anAngle);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var O:Orbiter = new Orbiter;

// Define the offset.
O.x = monster.x;
O.y = monster.y;

// Set radius and rotation speed.
O.radius = 110;
O.speed = 270;

// Enable the rotation processing.
O.start();

// Append items to orbit.
O.items.push(Crystal1);
O.items.push(Crystal2);
O.items.push(Crystal3);
```

You can change **radius** and **speed** any time, as well as add/remove items, thanks to motion smoothing that all will look equally fine.

Comment: Well, I'm definitely not doing it the hierarchical way. That would be really gross.

And I guess the solution wasn't going to be just a minor tweaking of my code, but an entirely different approach. I guess I'll be spending some time trying to figure out how to translate this into my current program. I never use the Timer or Point class for anything and I assume your "rotation" variable is not in reference to the rotation property of an object, but a unique variable.

Comment: Ah, first I created it not as a subclass of **Sprite**, so this declaration is not necessary now. Fixed. Also, I don't understand your disgust about option 1. It is the traditional Flash way of doing things.